# Help with Riemann integration

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f(x)$ be the function

$f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2,&\text{if }x\text{ is irrational}\\0,&\text{if }x\text{ is rational}\;.\end{cases}$

Is $f$ continuous? Is $f$ differentiable at any point? Is $f$ Riemann integrable on $[0, 1]$.

I am quite stuck on this question. I think that this function is not Riemann integrable but I am not sure. I also think that it is differentiable at $x = 0$ but I am not sure how to show this formally. Any help on how to approach this question would be appreciated.

Comment: $$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)}{h}$$

But, $0\le f(h)\leq h^2$,

So we have that $0\leq \frac{f(h)}{h}\leq h$

And thus, $f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)}{h}=0$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Take for example

$$x:=e\;,\;\;x_n:=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\;,\;\;\text{then}\;\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\,,\,x_n\in\Bbb Q\;,\;x_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}x=e\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$$

and

$$e^2=f(e)=f(x)\ne \lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}0=0$$

The above solves (why?) the questions about differentiability and continuity. About integrability:

Take any partition of the interval $\,[0,1]\;$ , and then **choose** inside each subinterval once a rational number and another time an irrational number (why can we do such a thing?). In the former case we get sums equal to zero whereas in the latter we don't, so...

Answer (score 1):

Every point of $\left(0;1\right]$ is a point of discontinuity. It's easy to show this fact if you consider $x+\Delta x$ for every point $x \in \left(0;1\right]$ in two cases: $\Delta x$ is rational or irrational, and show that $f(x+\Delta x)$ does not go to $0$.

In the same way you can show that at the point $x=0$ the function is continuous at this point. The question of integrability is rather simple -- this function has uncountable number of points of discontinuity and has measure >0, so this function is not integrated in Riemann's sense.

Comment: first: that there are uncountable discontinuity points does **not** mean the function isn't integrable Riemann: what's important is whereas the set of discontinuity points has (Lebesgue) measure *zero* , and second: I think there's a good chance someone making such a basic question as this one doesn't yet know the above theorem.

Comment: I've no idea where did you get all that from, @Paul :I'm not trying to teach you anything, I didn't accuse you, not even *close*, of incompetence or anything like that. Stop being so dramatic and focus on mathematics: you made a mistake just like many other have made before. I myself have made hundreds of them and when someone points that I don't feel like someone's trying to teach me things or accusing me of incompetence.

Comment: Ok, perhaps, today I have a very bad day. Anyway, thanks for explaining my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

For continuity: choose any irrational $x$ value other than 0 (for example, $x=\pi$) and a seqence of rationals $(a_n)$ that converges to $x$. Argue with sequence continuity.

For differentiability: look at the point $x=0$ and see what the difference quotient 
$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$ does when $x\to 0$.

For Integrability: Check out the example for $1_\mathbb{Q}$ on [Wikipedia (Riemann integral)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Examples)